# Python _winreg error accessing windows version on windows 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, winreg

I can see the value in my registry editor and the path is 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.

I want to print the product name which I can see is Windows 8, but when I am running my program to get the windows version on my 64 bit laptop:

```
def get_registry_value(key, subkey, value):
  import _winreg
  key = getattr(_winreg, key)
  handle = _winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey)
  (value, type) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(handle, value)
  return value

def os_version():
  def get(key):
    return get_registry_value(
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", 
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion",
        key)
  os = get("ProductName")
  sp = get("CSDVersion")
  build = get("CurrentBuildNumber")
  return "%s %s (build %s)" % (os, sp, build)
```

i am getting

> WindowsError: Error[2] "The system cannot find the file specified"

so  i modified the code as

```
key = getattr(_winreg, key)
handle = _winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey ,0 ,_winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
```

but i am still getting the same error 
Which part am I doing wrong? What can I do to get my version of the operating system ?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me on windows 7...

```
in > print os_version()
out > Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
```